# Custom Comparator for ConcurrentSkipListMap

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I need to define a customized comparator to ConcurrentSkipListMap, I use this code to sort based on 'LogicalClock' but the result is not as I expected. I create the key like this: "ClientId"+":"+"LogicalClock"

```
class Qentry{
    int  AckCount;
    int ClientID; 
    long LogicalClock;
}

Comparator<String> LogicalClockComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override public int compare(String k1, String k2) {
            if  (k1.compareTo(k2)==0)
                    return 0;
            return   (int)( Long.valueOf(k1.substring(k1.indexOf(":")+1)) -Long.valueOf(k2.substring(k1.indexOf(":")+1) ));
        }
ConcurrentSkipListMap<String,Qentry> q;
q =new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String,Qentry>(LogicalClockComparator);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo (or copy/paste error) to me, maybe you want to use (look at the end of the line)

```
return   (int)( Long.valueOf(k1.substring(k1.indexOf(":")+1)) -Long.valueOf(k2.substring(k2.indexOf(":")+1) ));
```

instead of what you had:

```
return   (int)( Long.valueOf(k1.substring(k1.indexOf(":")+1)) -Long.valueOf(k2.substring(k1.indexOf(":")+1) ));
```

Comment: I think I need a Pair programmer to check the typo. :D

Answer (score 1):

This would have surprising results for large time differences.  compare should only return -1, 0, or +1 but you can get away with larger ranges. For `long` you are like to get an overflow casting to an int which would have unexpected behaviour.

I suggest you use `Long.compare()` if its available and `Double.compare` if it is not.

BTW, as Maps don't allow duplicate keys, when you return 0, it treats it a as a duplicate so if you have `a:1`, `b:1` and `c:1` they are all duplicates.  The way around this is to compare the whole String if the comparison is equal.

BTW2 While this is pretty inefficient code you could use `parseLong` instead of `valueOf` to improve it slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the typo, note that you have 2 potential sources of overflow: when subtracting the 2 longs and when casting to int. It would probably be better to use:

```
Long value1 = Long.valueOf(k1.substring(k1.indexOf(":")+1));
Long value2 = Long.valueOf(k2.substring(k2.indexOf(":")+1));
return value1.compareTo(value2);
```